# Service access in beforeDelete()

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I want to call a service inside my grails domain objects beforeDelete() event. Unfortunately it always crashes reproducibly when the event is fired. I built an example that reproduces the problem. The domain object:

```
class Gallery {

    def myService

    def beforeDelete() {
            // System.out.println(myService); // not even this works, same error!
        System.out.println(myService.say());
    }
}
```

The service:

```
class MyService {

    String say() {
        "hello"
    }
}
```

The test controller:

```
class DeleteController {

    def index() {

        Gallery.list().each {
            it.delete()
        }
    }

    def create() {
        def gallery = new Gallery()
        gallery.save()
    }
}
```

If I start the application and call create followed by index I get:

```
Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [testbeforedelete.Gallery#1]
```

What I want to accomplish is to call my service, which is a bit more complicated than this example. I cannot explain this behavior and I don't know how cope with this. I know that the Hibernate events need special care yet I'm stuck.

Comment: Does your service modify/access the gallery instance which should be deleted? Did your simplified project (as posted above) also crashes?

Comment: try this instead in your index: Gallery.executeQuery("delete from Gallery")

Comment: @aiolos: No, the service does not modify the gallery instance. And yes, this simplified project crashes exactly as described, I have tested that.

Comment: @Raphael The index method was just an example. You can also try Gallery.first().delete() which results in the same error. Your code produces a different error: Not supported for DML operations [delete from testbeforedelete.Gallery]. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Not supported for DML operations [delete from testbeforedelete.Gallery]

Comment: The problem of your example is not the same of the `beforeDelete()`

Comment: Sorry, it was supposed to be executeUpdate not executeQuery.

Comment: When you query the database it returns a lazy collection, when you iterate over it deleting its members, you are altering the representation in the database, this throws hibernate off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The beforeDelete actually makes a change to your domainclass. I agree that you would not expect this behaviour. Hibernate thinks that you are modifying the instance. You could use the follow code to get around your problem

```
def beforeDelete() {
    Gallery.withNewSession {
        System.out.println(myService.say());
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested your code and it seems to work. But what is the explanation for that? Calling the service somehow messes with the hibernate session. And opening a new session avoids this. I want to understand whats happening here.